# What does "payment with return" mean?

Tags: meaning, translation, legalese

I'm working on translating document from English to Polish. The document is called "Account Transcript" and it is from the US Internal Revenue Service.

The Transactions table at the bottom contains a "Payment with return" item with code 610. I don't know what it means.

Could somebody please explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IRS *tax return* is the set of forms you fill out and send to the IRS to calculate and document the tax you owe. If you owe tax, and include the payment when you send in the forms, that's *payment with return*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I couldn't find that expression anywhere maybe because it's so simple.

Comment: Yeah, it's not an expression, it just means what the words say.

Comment: Related: [Why are tax returns called tax returns, and is the term applicable outside the US?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/479849/).