# Why are tax returns called tax returns, and is the term applicable outside the US?

Tags: etymology, terminology

I have a problem with the term *tax returns* regarding its genesis and use in international communication.

1) Genesis and logic

I do not understand the logic behind it. As far as I see, "tax returns" are actually *tax declarations*, i.e. a set of documents filed by e.g. an individual and sent to the government's financial authorities to declare his/her income, so that the government can decide on this individual's income tax. If this is correct, why is this called a "return"? Nothing gets returned here. A document gets handed out. There is even not money to be returned, rather there will be money to be paid. (Exception: German employees, on filing their tax declaration often get back parts of taxes paid on their behalf by the employer because employers are obliged to send part of the monthly salary directly to the financial authorities, and depending on circumstances, employees can get back overpaid taxes by the end of the year. This, I would say, is indeed literally a *tax return*.)

2) Usage

Clearly "tax return" is in use in the USA. Question: could or should I use it also in international contexts (everywhere outside the US)? Or should I better use a more generic term such as *tax declaration*?

Comment: One of the dictionary meanings of *return* is, in fact, a legal declaration. *Tax returns* and *election returns* are probably the only returns that an ordinary citizen encounters with any regularity, however.

Comment: The exception described in the parentheses is not specific to Germany: in many other countries, the government collects estimated taxes during the year, and then, after the tax returns are filed, refunds (returns) any overpayments.

Comment: @jsw  Yes, of course.I mentioned the German example simple as exactly this: an example.

Comment: I've always thought that it's called a 'return' because when tax was assessed on the basis of printed forms the forms were 'sent out' by the government and 'returned' by the taxpayers. If it predates the use of printed forms I'm sure that governments sent out requests for information before they devised the printed forms.

Comment: This question is seeking an elucidation of the connection between  the use of a word in the contexts of a certain special kind and its core meaning. It is difficult to understand how that is not a matter of English language and usage.

Answer (score 6):

See this definition for **return** (noun):

> An official report or statement submitted in response to a formal demand.
>   ‘census returns’
>   [SOURCE](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/return)

The *Oxford English Dictionary* has examples going back to 1618

Comment: The dictionary entry confirms that it is correct to use the term in this sense, but the OP already knows that well. The OP is asking about 'the logic behind it': **why** is it called a *return*, given that nothing actually gets returned?

Comment: @jsw29 Word meanings don't require "logic," however, at least when the meaning of words has shifted over time since their introduction. According to the OED, the sense of *return* as a report or declaration is an extension of *return* referring to a report of election (which would be delivered by a sheriff returning to court), from Anglo-Norman *retourner* for submitting a writ to a court with a report, from vulgar Latin *retorno* meaning to deter or turn back, ultimately from *tornus*, Latin for *lathe*.

Comment: @choster, of course, word meanings often develop without any 'logic' (i.e. often the answer to the question why we use some word in a certain way is: we just do), but in many cases there is an explanation of how different meanings of a word are related; one may be wondering whether this is such a case, and your comment suggests that it is. Why not post the comment as an answer?

Comment: @choster  Yes, when I wrote "logic" I meant it rather in the sense of "the original thought behind the word". With your description of referring a report of election to court you seem to give a very plausible explanation based on mediaevel society. Could you elaborate a bit? What election would be meant? Villagers electing their spokesman vis-a-vis the regional strongman (or aristocrat, if you prefer), or a king? Or parishes electing a priest (which in some parts of Christianity was common practice, at least theoretically), and sending a messenger to court to give notice about the new cleric?

Comment: @choster "Word meanings don't require "logic," however ..." they say. It is clear, then, that the subsequent attempt at an explanation is possibly illogical: *because the OED said so!!!!!* That's, however, not how any of this works.

Answer (score 2):

It is used outside the US

here is a UK sub reddit using it:

https://www.reddit.com/r/CasualUK/comments/ac52ln/selfemployed_casualukers_lets_all_procrastinate/

It's probably more prevalent in the US because the US tax system requires more people to do one (most people in the UK will not have to submit a tax return at all)

Comment: For clarification: most people in the UK don't submit a tax return because when they receive their monthly salary, appropriate tax in already deducted by the employer and sent to the government. In the U.S., I guess you receive your untaxed salary every month and therefore everyone has to submit their tax return each year.

Comment: @bikashg I believe the issue in the states is they have lots of complicated things they can deduct from their taxes, in comparison most Brits only have pension contributions and thats done by paying them before tax

Answer (score -4):

Since the government issues the currency, paying some of it back to the issuer in the form of taxes is a return of the money.

Comment: Answers should be based on linguistics, not logic. This answer would be improved by finding sources for the meaning of _tax returns_.